# Use past or present tense?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I was about to give my daughter a shower and I saw that she did not clean her toothbrush last time she used it so I said

> Please clean your toothbrush after you **use** it.

I did not say the word "always" but I meant that. Then she corrected me as

> Please clean your toothbrush after you **used** it.

I am confused. Which one is correct? Or are they both correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't be confident in your understanding of English being better than your daughter's, there's no hope for you. ;)

Joking aside, you're correct: for your daughter's version to be right, it would have to be "Please clean your toothbrush after you **have** used it." The form you've used, an example of an [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood), inherently implies "use it" as a continual, repeating action to which the instruction applies, so there's nothing wrong with that construction.

That said,

> Always clean your toothbrush after you have used it.

or even

> Always clean your toothbrush after using it.

would be best, as the first one may confuse your daughter into thinking you only mean on that one occasion; it can mean that too. Nothing wrong with making it absolutely clear you mean for her to do it every time she brushes her teeth. :)

Edit: After some discussion on Language Overflow, I agree with one of the other users who pointed out that "after use" might be a bit too formal for a child, so I've changed my suggestion to "after using it".